# Windows 7 thinks every folder is shared

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, robocopy

I have a hard drive that I'm moving thousands of folders off, which I would do either using `robocopy /mov` or windows explorer cut and paste. Robocopy won't move the folders, and explorer prompts me for each folder. you can see the prompt, plus my actual shares:

[image: windows prompt]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez222.png)

the folder isn't shared according to the properties or advanced properties:
[image]
[image]

Windows doesn't let me do a "Continue all" (too helpful). Moving the folder to a different location on the same hard disk prompts for each folder, I "Continue" for each of the thousand-odd button presses, then if I try to move them again, they still think they are shared. This happens for both folders and the files within the folders. Awesome work, Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the folder is being shared because it has a parent that is being shared.

How to get some more information that will help to fix this:  Try: Start, Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Computer Management.  In left frame, under "Computer Management (Local)", System Tools, Shared Folders, choose Shares.

If that doesn't answer your question, please get to a command prompt, type "Net Share", and post the results, because that will probably help us to be able to troubleshoot more specifically.

Comment: The folders aren't shared. The parent folders aren't shared. The drive its on isn't shared. http://i.imgur.com/0of7cmC.png shows what is shared - it's all the usual administrative things, but none relates to this drive or these folders.

Comment: Okay, here's another idea: maybe the "share" doesn't mean "network file sharing".  Maybe it just means another user is using the file.  Try opening [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sf.net) and "Find Handles or DLLS" (on the _H_acker menu; or use Process Explorer which has similar capability), and search for jpod

Comment: after msconfig to turn of all startup processes, scheduling a scandisk on reboot on the drive, rebooting the machine, unplugging it from the network, moving the folder still prompts "if you move this folder, it will no longer be shared"